# Content não funciona no Firefox - CSS

Tags: css

Eu tenho um progress bar onde nele eu coloco um content atribuindo a percentagem, conforme o código:

```
progress {
  text-align: center;
  height: 18px;
  width: 65px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 80px;
  /* Set the progressbar to relative */
  position: relative;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: white;
}

progress:before {
  content: attr(data-label) " %";
  font-size: 0.8em;
  vertical-align: 0;
  border-radius: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}


progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #c9c9c9;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #7cb342;
  border-radius: 80px;
  
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #7cb342;
  border-radius: 80px;

}
```

```html
<progress data-label="100" />
```

No Firefox, o progress bar fica assim
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em outros navegadores fica certo, que é assim[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tem alguma forma de resolver isso no Firefox??

Comment: Parece que o FF não aceita pseudo elemento na tag progress

Answer (score 0):

Experimenta acrescentar no progress o seguinte:

```
border: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

É o necessário para meter a funcionar no Firefox.

Comment: Pior que não deu certo...

Comment: Eu guiei-me por aqui, da uma vista de olhos e experimenta algo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480331/firefox-styling-of-progress-bar-value